# which version of the sonar scanner is supported for the msbuild v17

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

## Starting: Run Code Analysis

Task         : Run Code Analysis
Description  : Run scanner and upload the results to the SonarQube server.
Version      : 4.6.3
Author       : sonarsource
Help         : This task is not needed for Maven and Gradle projects since the scanner should be run as part of the build.

## [More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)

E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\4.6.3\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end
(node:164) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:164) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:164) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:164) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.6.2
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Post-processing started.
18:16:56.639  18:16:56.639  WARNING: Failed to find the code coverage command line tool. Possible cause: Visual Studio is not installed, or the installed version does not support code coverage.
WARNING: The following projects do not have a valid ProjectGuid and were not built using a valid solution (.sln) thus will be skipped from analysis...
E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\EnumsLibraries.Core\EnumsLibraries.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.Core\Casepoint.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.ServiceChannel.Core\Casepoint.ServiceChannel.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Common\DFCoreAPI.Core\DFCoreAPI.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Common\Casepoint.ResourceAPI.Core\Casepoint.ResourceAPI.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Common\Casepoint.RepositoryAPI.Core\Casepoint.RepositoryAPI.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\BusinessAccessLayer\Casepoint.BAL.Billing.Core\Casepoint.BAL.Billing.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\BusinessAccessLayer\Casepoint.BAL.BPMS.Core\Casepoint.BAL.BPMS.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Common\ProcessingAPI.Core\ProcessingAPI.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\BusinessAccessLayer\Casepoint.BAL.Cloud.Core\Casepoint.BAL.Cloud.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.ImportExport.Core\Casepoint.ImportExport.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\TimeZoneLibrary.Core\TimeZoneLibrary.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.DataAccessLayer.Core\Casepoint.DataAccessLayer.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.AutoSize.Core\Casepoint.AutoSize.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\BusinessAccessLayer\Casepoint.BAL.eDD.Core\Casepoint.BAL.eDD.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Common\Casepoint.CloudSDK.Core\Casepoint.CloudSDK.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Common\Casepoint.ServiceSDK.Core\Casepoint.ServiceSDK.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Common\DFRequestAPI.Core\DFRequestAPI.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\APIRatelimit.Core\APIRatelimit.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.Aspose.Core\Casepoint.Aspose.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.ImageProperty.Core\Casepoint.ImageProperty.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Litexn.DataTypes.Core\Litexn.DataTypes.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.NativeRedactionGatewayInterface.Core\Casepoint.NativeRedactionGatewayInterface.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.Cache.Core\Casepoint.Cache.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.VirusIdentification.Core\Casepoint.VirusIdentification.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Web\Casepoint.API.Core\Casepoint.API.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.Web.Core\Casepoint.Web.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\BusinessAccessLayer\Casepoint.BAL.Core\Casepoint.BAL.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\FileProcessingLib.Core\FileProcessingLib.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\Casepoint.ResourceManager.Core\Casepoint.ResourceManager.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\BusinessAccessLayer\Casepoint.BAL.DFCore.Core\Casepoint.BAL.DFCore.Core.csproj, E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Common\Logger.Core\Logger.Core.csproj
WARNING: Duplicate ProjectGuid: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". The project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: "E:\DevOps\Agent_Net6-Web_work\1\s\code\Framework\EnumsLibraries.Core\EnumsLibraries.Core.csproj"
##[error]No analysable projects were found. SonarQube analysis will not be performed. Check the build summary report for details.
No analysable projects were found. SonarQube analysis will not be performed. Check the build summary report for details.

i want to run my pipeline with out error